# How to save the current compiler?

Tags: compiler

Say that I have a `compiler/foo.vim` compiler file.
Next, I want to define command a command that change compiler, run it and change the compiler back to the original.
For example:

```
command! MyCommand {
    var previous_compiler = ???? # save info about the current compiler. How?!
    compiler foo
    silent make 
    execute "compiler " .. previous_compiler
    copen
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I can self-answer my own question. It is enough to use `b:current_compiler` variable.

```
command! MyCommand {
    var previous_compiler = ""
    if exists("b:current_compiler")
        previous_compiler = b:current_compiler
    endif
    compiler erlang
    silent make
    if strlen(previous_compiler) > 0
        execute "compiler " .. previous_compiler
    endif
    copen
}
```

Comment: strlen > 0: `!empty(previous_compiler)`. Also `execute 'compiler' previous_compiler` should suffice, though that may have been changed for vim9script.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a very simple compiler script taken from Vim's own runtime (`$VIMRUNTIME/compiler/eslint.vim`):

```
" Vim compiler file
" Compiler:    ESLint for JavaScript
" Maintainer:  Romain Lafourcade <XXX@YYY>
" Last Change: 2020 August 20

if exists("current_compiler")
  finish
endif
let current_compiler = "eslint"

if exists(":CompilerSet") != 2
  command -nargs=* CompilerSet setlocal <args>
endif

CompilerSet makeprg=npx\ eslint\ --format\ compact
CompilerSet errorformat=%f:\ line\ %l\\,\ col\ %c\\,\ %m,%-G%.%#
```

Take all the time you need to read that snippet *carefully*, line by line.

Now, how would you save the **current compiler**?.

Comment: By reading at the script above I would `var previous_compiler = current_compiler` but that won't work since `current_compiler` is limited to the `eslint.vim` scope (it is enough to `:echo current_compiler` from any other buffer to get E121). However, using `b:current_compiler` seems to work, as I answered below (we posted an answer at the same time).